# Ajax.BeginForm - possible bug - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If you have `Html.Hidden(...)` inside `Ajax.BeginForm` and you submit the form more than once and you're updating the value of the hidden field using `ViewData` or whatever, it won't update.  Maybe because `Html.Hidden` is a server-side control. (`Html.Hidden` is inside the UpdateTargetId div)

Another way things would break is if there is an `Html.TextBox` inside `Ajax.BeginForm` or something and you need to hide/show it based on what comes out of that Ajax Request using some kind of if, else clause.  It won't appear/disappear.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked million times here and I've answered it million times - this is by design: HTML helpers always use the POSTed value when binding before looking at the ViewData or model. This basically means that you **cannot** change the value in the controller action and this is by design. You could write your own html helper if you don't like this design or simply:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<%: ViewData["foo"] %>" />
```

If you use html helper:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("foo") %>
```

if there's a POSTed value `foo` it is this value that is going to be used no matter what you put in `ViewData`.

Comment: but that still leaves out my second concern. Hiding/showing Html.TextBoxx based on what the model contains.

Comment: Your second concern is totally non-understandable. All I understood is hiding/showing and appearing disappearing. Maybe you could try to be a little more specific. Can't you just test the value of the model in the view and based on this value include or not include this TextBox?

Comment: that's exactly what I was doing. Test the value of the model in the view and based on this value include or not this TexBox.  When I debug the code, it's even hitting the right "if" clause.  Why it's not outputting that on screen is my concern.

Comment: all of this "if-else" clause was inside a table, and I rearranged column here and there, and it started working for FireFox.  It was already working for ie8.